# Text to Speech in Hindi language

Tags: android, text, speech, hindi

I'm working on Text to Speech Application. I want to read a string in hindi like **"हालाँकि सूर के जीवन के बारे में कई जनश्रुतियाँ प्रचलित हैं, पर इन में कितनी सच्चाई है यह कहना कठिन है**"  to speech 
here is my code but it's not working please help me how to set up hindi language please help me ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String string;
private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
private TextToSpeech myTTS;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    string="हालाँकि सूर के जीवन के बारे में कई जनश्रुतियाँ प्रचलित हैं, पर इन में कितनी सच्चाई है यह कहना कठिन है";
    StartSpeak(string);
}

private void StartSpeak(final String data) {
    myTTS=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int initStatus) {
            if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                myTTS.setLanguage(new Locale("hin", "IND", "variant"));
                // start speak
                speakWords(data);
            }
            else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


    });
}

private void speakWords(String speech) {
    myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

}

Comment: writ the string phonetically and try it. Hope it will work

Comment: Phonetically ????sorry I didn't get you can u please give me an example???

Comment: string="halanki sur ke jivan  ke baare me kai janshrutiya prachalit hai " like this

Comment: I think u didnot understand my question properly I want to read a hindi text(not in english script) is that possible ?